# Path to assets folder on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I'm coding something into CodeIgniter and I want to apply a css template. I found one I like and download it.

After merging the css code with the code I have before the merging, I found that the images used by the css template doesn't load. Originally they should stay on root of html folder (or www, or public_html, you know what I mean...), but I put them under an assets folder which is on same level as system folder.

Something like this...

```
Website Folder
|
|---application\
|-----(CodeIgniter application folders...)
|---assets\
|-----style.css
|-----css\
|-------mini.css
|-----images\
|-----js\
|-----robots.txt
|---system
|-----(CodeIgniter system folder...)
|index.php
```

I googled for a couple of hours and I found [this post](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/62527/#307910) (post #5). I try what the OP says but it doesn't work.

I can autoload the url_helper adding

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

to the autoload.php file. But when I add

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url() ?>"/>
```

the images are still absent.

The original html file has this line

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

so, I'm guessing that I should add assets/ so it looks

```
<link href="assets/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but still the images are missing.

If I move the contents of assets folder to root, everything is fine, but of course, that's not a good practice AFAIK...

My base_url is

```
http://localhost/prog/nonsense/mvc/
```

Before you ask, yes, I did read the .htacces solutions, but I really don't want to mess with .htaccess editing for now.

A little help here could be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

have you check `.htaccess` ?
It must have something like:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|upload|robots\.txt|.*\.css)
```

Comment: I haven't edited my .htacces becase I don't want to edit it unless it's stricly neccesary... but even if I replace 'Deny from all' with the that code, the images are missing...

Comment: what have you got when access this link: http://localhost/prog/nonsense/mvc/assets/images/templatemo_style.css

Comment: Ok, I saw and error that I haven't spoted before. My path should be  'localhost/prog/nonsense/mvc/assets/style.css' but even so... now some images are missing...

Comment: please check those images full path, or you can use firebug to find those full path

Comment: Thank you @zerokavn. Very nifty that firebug addon.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same thing as you, and I call them like this:

```
<link href="<?=base_url('assets/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

This works for me if the `base_url()` is set and the `url` helper is called.

I call the `base_url()` and then the `assets` folder then `style.css`. There's no need for a `/` after `base_url();?>` because there's one in the `base_url()` anyway.

**Another option using codeigniter's built in HTML function:**

Also, if you look at [this link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag), you'll see you can use the `HTML` helper and call it via codeigniter's built in functions.

This time, you shouldn't need `base_url();`

do:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html');
```

then in the view for header add this:

```
<?=link_tag('assets/style.css');?>
```

It will output to this:

```
<link href="http://localhost/prog/nonsense/mvc/assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is what I'm using. My problem was that I'm kindy tired and I'm coding crap, and besides that I haven't detected a couple of paths that should be converted from relative to full. That firebug addon is really really helpful. Anyway, thanks for answer :)

Comment: Ok, no worries @Ashir! In future look at some of codeigniter's built in functions too though, as they can save you a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

base_url could also be used as link_tag:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

would work too and keep your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

yes! I just added the following line in `.htacces` file it working fine

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just add one line in .**htacces** side of application folder

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
```