# In codeigniter, how to make assets folder work by putting it in the application folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to put my assets folder inside the application folder of codeigniter just like:

```
application > assets > css > style.css
```

and I want to give assets files links in my view files.

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303268/path-to-assets-folder-on-codeigniter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to load css file in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697954/how-to-load-css-file-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Sounds fine. What is your question? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice in codeigniter for set up the assets as below flow:

- application
- assets
- system

But you want:

- application > assets > css > style.css
- system

but if you want to keep the assets folder inside the application, then you've to do some extra functionality as below:
First, make sure that  you've loaded the URL helper in your controller which is:

```
$this->load->helper("url");
```

you have to first create a helper named "my_helper.php" at "application/helpers" directory with this code:

```
if ( ! function_exists('asset_url()'))
{
  function asset_url() {

    return base_url().'application/assets/';

  }
}
```

Now, you have to load this helper into your controller as below:

```
$this->load->helper("my_helper");
```

Now replace your .htaccess code at 'application/'' directory with the below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

After doing all the above functionality, you have to declare your assets in view as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>css/style.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Set up library: **application folder->config folder->autoload.php**
2. In **autoload.php** find **$autoload['helper'] = array('url');** and add **'url'** in it.
3. 1st create **folder assets** in **application**. 2nd create **folder CSS** in **assets** and put the **.css** file in it.
4. Called the CSS file with this style **< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/yourFileName.css" >**